# Subgroups of $\Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Find all subgroups of $\Bbb Z_5 \times \Bbb Z_5$.
I can see that the non-trivial ones are of order $5$. But how do I find them exactly?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Groups of order 5 are cyclic...

Comment: List the non-trivial ones.  First coordinate could be always $0$. In all other cases, everything is known once we know the number $b$ such that $(1,b)$ is in the subgroup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We list the subgroups of order $5$. There is the group generated by $(0,1)$. Then there are the groups generated by $(1,b)$, where $b$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  That's all. We can if we wish give the addition table for each.

Comment: You are welcome. In this very concrete situation, we can really get our hands on the objects, with little machinery needed.